# como capturar pantalla de una ventana windows .bat

Tags: cmd, batch

que tal estoy tratando de capturar la pantalla de una ventana en cuanto un proceso se termina de ejecutar tengo mi archivo .BAT aqui

```
pushd \\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200
set /a fecha=%date:~0,2% -1
MKDIR  "%fecha%"
copy \\10.100.14.12\Sterling\Recibe\R200_CMG.txt  \\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200\"%fecha%"\R200_CMG.txt
copy \\10.100.14.12\Sterling\Recibe\GEST_CMG.txt  \\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200\"%fecha%"\GEST_CMG.txt
start %windir%\explorer.exe "\\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200\"%fecha%"\"
```

entonces solo quiero capturar la pantalla que sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

descarge el famoso nircmd
pero solo me deja capturar la pantalla dentro de donde esta el archivo y no requiero copiarlo el ejecutable cada que se ejecuta el .bat
solo quiero tomar una captura y guardarla en una carpeta o mandarla por email

Comment: Tienes el código en PHP o c#?

Comment: perdon es un .bat

Comment: es de el cmd simbolo del sistema

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolvi solo tenia que agregar la ruta donde esta el programa y despues agregar
el script que ejecuta en la carpeta donde se va a guardar

```
pushd c:\ruta
nircmd.exe cmdwait 4000 savescreenshot  C:\10.100.99.74\img~$currdate.MM_dd_yyyy$.png
```